# Group by with extra features MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite, group-by

I'm trying to get sum for all Key For all years(separate) there is more than one in each year, and takeng information from three DB
I can do it for one year, but how to do it from all. There ara actually two years 1996 and 1997

This is how to get everything for 1996 and almost the same how to get for 1997
But how to join them orr get everithing correctly

```
SELECT OrderID, CustomerID, OrderDate, sum(Cost) as TotalCost
FROM (SELECT Orders.CustomerID, Orders.OrderID, Orders.OrderDate, Orders.OrderID, OrderDetails.ProductID, (OrderDetails.Quantity* Products.Price) as Cost
             FROM Orders, OrderDetails, Products
             WHERE Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID
             AND OrderDetails.ProductID= Products.ProductID)
WHERE OrderDate<="1996-12-31"
Group by CustomerID
```

here is tables what I have 
Orders

```
+---------+------------+------------+------------+-----------+
| OrderID | CustomerID | EmployeeID | OrderDate  | ShipperID |
+---------+------------+------------+------------+-----------+
|   10248 |         90 |          5 | 1996-07-04 |         3 |
|   10249 |         81 |          6 | 1996-07-05 |         1 |
|   10250 |         34 |          4 | 1996-07-08 |         2 |
|   10251 |         84 |          3 | 1997-07-08 |         1 |
|   10252 |         76 |          4 | 1997-07-09 |         2 |
+---------+------------+------------+------------+-----------+
```

OrderDetails

```
+---------------+---------+-----------+----------+
| OrderDetailID | OrderID | ProductID | Quantity |
+---------------+---------+-----------+----------+
|             1 |   10248 |        1 |       12 |
|             2 |   10248 |        2 |       10 |
|             3 |   10248 |        3 |        5 |
|             4 |   10249 |        1 |        9 |
|             5 |   10249 |        2 |       40 |
|             6 |   10250 |        1 |       10 |
|             7 |   10250 |        2 |       35 |
|             8 |   10250 |        3 |       15 |
+---------------+---------+-----------+----------+
```

and Products

```
+-----------+--+------------+------------+--+-------+
| ProductID |  | SupplierID | CategoryID |  | Price |
+-----------+--+------------+------------+--+-------+
|         1 |  |          1 |          1 |  |    18 |
|         2 |  |          1 |          1 |  |    19 |
|         3 |  |          1 |          2 |  |    10 |
+-----------+--+------------+------------+--+-------+
```

I Use MySQL
Sorry for long post

P.S. it said

> no such function: year

P.P.S. I used to use SQLlite

Comment: it said that there is no year function, may be type of OrderDate colomn is wrong

Comment: "No such function: year"  - this error message format is typical of sqlite, not mysql. Are you sure that you use mysql, and not sqlite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the year() mysql function to extract the year part from a date:

```
select o.customerid, year(o.orderdate) as year, sum(od.Quantity* p.Price) as totalcost
from orders o
inner join orderdetails od on o.orderid=od.orderid
inner join products p on od.productid=p.productid
group by o.customerid, year(o.orderdate)
```

Update:

Based on the error message you may be using sqlite and not mysql. In this case use substr() function to get the 4 leftmost characters, otherwise the logic is the same:

```
select o.customerid, substr(o.orderdate,1,4) as year, sum(od.Quantity*  p.Price) as totalcost
from orders o
inner join orderdetails od on o.orderid=od.orderid
inner join products p on od.productid=p.productid
group by o.customerid, substr(o.orderdate,1,4)
```

Answer (score 2):

You would include `year(OrderDate)` in the aggregation:

```
SELECT OrderID, CustomerID, year(OrderDate), sum(Cost) as TotalCost
FROM (SELECT Orders.CustomerID, Orders.OrderID, Orders.OrderDate, Orders.OrderID, OrderDetails.ProductID, (OrderDetails.Quantity* Products.Price) as Cost
      FROM Orders JOIN
           OrderDetails
           ON Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID JOIN
           Products
           ON OrderDetails.ProductID = Products.ProductID
     ) x
WHERE OrderDate <= '1996-12-31'
Group by CustomerID, year(OrderDate);
```

Actually, the subquery is unnecessary and you should use table aliases:

```
SELECT o.CustomerID, year(o.OrderDate), SUM(od.Quantity * p.Price) as Cost
FROM Orders o JOIN
     OrderDetails od
     ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID JOIN
     Products p
     ON od.ProductID = p.ProductID
GROUP BY CustomerId, year(OrderDate)
```

Comment: 1. You should take orderid out of the outer select. 2. Why do you need a subquery?

Comment: And now you have posted exactly the same solution as I have :)

Comment: but it sayes that there is no year function

Comment: Year() function is available in mysql since its conception, I believe.

Comment: yes I belive you but here it doesn't work http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_delete